# Simple Symfony2 event seemingly setup, but not firing

Tags: symfony

I am trying to set up a simple event listener to execute some code at the start of and before every request. I'm just trying to echo out a simple message to check it's all working.

If I make a mistake (e.g. a typo) or wrongly configure (like I have for the last 30 minutes) then it returns various error messages. But I think I have it setup as the error messages have gone.

This is my code:

I have added this to my /app/config.yml file

```
services:
    kernel.listener.request_listener:
        class: Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And this is the code in the related file

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent("hello");

        $event->setResponse($response);     

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have hooked into a wrong event `kernel.exception`, which is called/dispatched only when exception occurs.

I believe you should have hooked the `kernel.request` event,

```
services:
    kernel.listener.request_listener:
        class: Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

`kernel.request` is called/dispatched on every request, and before starting to handle a request.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#handling-requests

> Before doing anything else, the kernel.request event is notified -- if one of the listeners returns a Response, it jumps to step 8 directly;

Comment: Perfect. Got it. I'll come back when it allows me to accept an answer (7 minutes). Thanks